# Building an AST with ANTLR 4

Tags: java, compiler-construction, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm creating a DSL which eventually has to be translated into Java source code. I'm using ANTLR 4 to generate a parse tree (using the Visitor tree walking method) to parse pieces of code written in the DSL based on the grammar file. I'm creating a Java AST directly in my visit methods.

Can anyone confirm/decline whether this is good practice? Or would it be beneficial if I constructed an AST for my DSL before transforming that AST into a Java one?

Example (AS IS, directly constructing a Java AST):

```
@Override
public JavaNode visitPrintExp(PrintExpContext ctx) {
    JavaExprNode jen = (JavaExprNode) visit(ctx.exp());
    JavaPrintNode jpn = new JavaPrintNode(jen);
    return jpn;
}
```

With following grammar rule:

printExp: 'print('exp')';

Proposal:

```
@Override
public DSLNode visitPrintExp(PrintExpContext ctx) {
    DSLExprNode den = (DSLExprNode) visit(ctx.exp());
    DSLPrintNode dpn = new DSLPrintNode(den);
    return dpn;
}
```

Comment: This may be a tad too opinion-based for SO. My opinion: this is perfect. ANTLR is constructing its own AST for your DSL; no need for another one. Walking ANTLR's tree is fine.

Comment: I'm confused after reading the post below. Essentially, I don't know whether it is worth the "duplication" of constructing an intuitive AST instead of using the generated parse tree in order to generate Java source code. Article: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/02/16/abstract-vs-concrete-syntax-trees/

Comment: All the blog is saying is that an automatically generated AST is going to have the structure of the grammar, and if you want some different structure which is easier for processing,  you're going to have to create it yourself. But the truth is that most of the time an automatically generated one is just fine: most grammars are far less ugly than C declarations!